# Transform Kafka Topic Data while saving on DB connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm pushing data on Kafka Topic Say TEST and then using confluent sink i'm saving it on oracle db. Now i need to transform the data while saving it .

I have a request object and a transaction id ... i'm saving that transaction id as key and Request object as value. I need to convert it to following columns of oracle db row :
`{transaction id , request object , timestamp}..` how can we configure it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could use KafkaStreams *Transformations* here: define your custom transformer class to change your input records before storing to DB.

Take a look here: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms

and here:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/